# ¿Cómo poner la zona horaria de España peninsular en PHP?

Tags: php

Estoy realizando un programa y necesito poner la zona horaria de Madrid con PHP (es decir, GMT+1). El caso es que ejecuto este código:

```
echo "La fecha de ejecución del programa es " . date("d") . " del " . date("m") . " de " . date("Y"). "a la hora". idate("H").":".idate("i").":".idate("s").".";
```

y me sale todo correcto menos la hora, en el sentido de que me sale una hora menos de la que me tiene que aparecer. Por ejemplo, ahora esto da la siguiente salida:

```
La fecha de ejecución del programa es 18 del 11 de 2020 a la hora 9:43:37.
```

El tema es que es una hora más. ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo de forma limpia? Porque podría poner `idate("H")+1` pero eso habría que cambiarlo cada vez que hay un cambio de hora y quiero que sea automático. Muchas gracias, saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para el uso horario existe en Php una función llamada **date_default_timezone_set($identificador_de_zona_horaria)** que establece el uso horario que usan las funciones de fecha y hora.
Para mostrar lo que tú quieres te dejo dos ejemplos que puedes implementar en tu código:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Madrid");
print "<p>Ejemplo 1: " . date("d/m/y H:i:s") . "</p>\n";
print "<p>Ejemplo 2: " . date("l, F jS Y ") . "</p>\n";
?>
```

Espero haberte ayudado, un saludo.